# User and Member Authentication via Bearer Token Problem

Tags: c#, authentication, umbraco, .net-6.0, bearer-token

im working on a Project with Umbraco 9.5.0 and im Facing an Issue with the Authentication via JWT Token. I need to authenticated users and members Based on a BearerToken which gets passed from our Proxy to the Umbraco APP, which works fine for each Type of User if i only use it only for members or users, but not for both at the same time.

The problem which we encounter comes from setting, i know that and only left it in place to give you guys the complete Picture,

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{ 
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = scheme; 
});
```

because in order for the Tokens to get validated we actually need to challenge them, and without setting the `DefaultChallengeScheme` those events are not triggering. But this is also the crux which we face. Because we need to provide one scheme for users and one scheme for members and therefor we actually override the ChallengeScheme.
We already tried to use the `AddScheme` method, but then we get an exception when we try to actually configure the scheme it self within the AddMemberLogin/AddBackOfficeLogin.

If Someone faced a similar Issue feel free to leave a comment, or even better an answer.
StartUp.cs

```
services.AddUmbraco(Environment, Configuration)
    .AddBackOffice()
    .AddWebsite()
    .AddComposers()
    .AddExternalMemberLogin()
    .AddExternalBackofficeLogin()  
    .Build();
```

ExtensionMethods:

```
        public static IUmbracoBuilder AddExternalBackofficeLogin(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
            builder.Config.Bind("Umbraco:Authentication", authenticationConfiguration);

            var scheme = $"{Constants.Security.BackOfficeExternalAuthenticationTypePrefix}{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{ 
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = scheme; 
});

            builder.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(logins =>
            {
                logins.AddBackOfficeLogin(authBuilder =>
                {
                    authBuilder.SchemeForBackOffice(scheme);
                    authBuilder.AddJwtBearer(scheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authenticationConfiguration.IdentityTokenSecret)),
                            ValidIssuer = authenticationConfiguration.Issuer,
                            ValidAudience = authenticationConfiguration.Audience,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateIssuer = true
                        };
                        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                        {
                            OnTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                            {
                               return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
        }

public static IUmbracoBuilder AddExternalMemberLogin(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
            builder.Config.Bind("Portal:Authentication", authenticationConfiguration);

            var scheme = $"{Constants.Security.MemberExternalAuthenticationTypePrefix}{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{ 
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = scheme; 
});
            builder.AddMemberExternalLogins(loginsBuilder =>
            {

                loginsBuilder.AddMemberLogin(authBuilder =>
                {

                    authBuilder.SchemeForMembers(scheme);
                    authBuilder.AddJwtBearer(scheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authenticationConfiguration.IdentityTokenSecret)),
                            ValidIssuer = authenticationConfiguration.Issuer,
                            ValidAudience = authenticationConfiguration.Audience,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateIssuer = true
                        };
                        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                        {
                            OnAuthenticationFailed = (a) =>
                            {
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            },
                            OnTokenValidated = (a) =>
                            {
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
                    });
                });

            });
            return builder;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but looking at it I think you need move the actions so they are constructed inside the same AddAuthentication block, otherwise is setting up them up once then possibly overwriting with the authentication scheme?

Is that the sort of behaviour you are seeing, so the last method that is called in the chain the scheme that is applied?

Comment: @Netferret thats exactly what i would normaly do, but umbraco has 2 identity tracks, and therefore you need to register 2 schemes. umbraco is even so paranoid that it validates that the scheme matches a certain naming guidline, and if it doesnt it changes it automatically, which results in no token validation at all.